# Android Image png color not true

Tags: android, image, png

I'm using pngs created from Photoshop (ie gradients, buttons etc...) . They are blue in color but show up in Android with more purple tint to them. I tried putting the images in the raw folder no no avail & I tried:

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() 
    {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        // Eliminates color banding
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

        window.setDither(true);
     }
```

This gets rid of banding in the gradients, but still does not show the true color of what I created on Photoshop. Is there any way to get it close?

Comment: Different color spaces? Different gamma? Once you've got a truecolor image on both ends, those are the two main reasons for color differences.

Comment: Just a thought, but is it possible your desktop monitor isn't correctly calibrated? It seems much more likely that color calibration on Android is accurate given that the device makers have control over their screens.

Comment: Why dont you mark some of questions as answered? I'm sure you've gotten at least one acceptable answer by this point...

Comment: @Matthew - Calibration helped a bit, at least it seems closer...

Comment: @ Kurru - I would but how to I accept a particular answer?

Comment: You can use the green checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, but is it possible your desktop monitor isn't correctly calibrated? It seems much more likely that color calibration on Android is accurate given that the device makers have control over their screens.

Comment: adding my comment as an answer, since it seems it might have solved the problem